# Are there any examples of a Shudras upgrading their Varna in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: varna, shudra

Although there are multiple examples in Hindu scriptures where Kshatriyas became brahmins (Kaushik, Harit, Moudgalaya Gotra and many others have Kshatriya men as progenitors).

But Are there any examples of Shudras upgrading their Varna in Hindu scriptures ?

Answer (score 2):

I have not come across any specific example of Shudras upgrading Varna. However, it is explicitly stated that Shudras have attained moksha.

**All has attained moksha**

> In different ages many beings with Rajas and Tamas predominating in
> them - Asuras, Rakshas, beasts, birds, Gandharvas, Apsaras, serpents,
> Siddhas, Charanas, Guhyakas, Vidyadharas, and among human beings,
> unqualified persons like **women, Vaisyas, Sudras and outcastes - all
> have attained to My being by the power of holy association alone.**
> .....

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.12.3-7**

Comment: Sir, the word unqualified seems to be an exaggeration.

Comment: I think unqualified is an euphemism for socially oppressed.